# Is it possible to pass a value to an order by clause using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have strange requirement on sql store procedure. I have rqst,key and keyType tables. Rqst table columns hold the FK of different master tables like status,requesType and processType. Key table hold the rqstId as FK in one of the column. keyType is master table used in key table.

My dats looks some thing like this
**RqstTable**

```
rqstId appId statsId procesTypId requestType updtBy createDt  orchiveId
10125   3       102     5           4          Test    date    c1235a
```

**keyTable**

```
keyId rqstId keyTypeId KeyValue  
123   10125  2          9586
```

**KeyTypeTable**

```
KeyTypeId KeyTypeName Description     
1           key1        key1des    
2           key2        key2des
```

My requirement is user will provide these Input fields `status,requestType, processType and date`. Also It should be `order by key3 from keyTypeTable`.

As per my searching we can not pass value to column in order by clause and As per documentation we can pass expression as part of order by. I tired scalr subquery like

```
select * from rqst a,
left join key b on b.rqstId = a.rqstId
left join KeyType c on c.keyTypeId = b.KeyTypeId
where a.procesTypId = 5 and a.requestType = 4 and a.statsId = 102
order by KeyTypeName; -- but want some thing like KeyTypeName='key2'
```

But the result is same as with out order by clause.it did not work.

My expected out would be

```
KeyValue  rqstId  orchiveId   
9586      10125   c1235a
```

I am writting my sql using Oracle for this.

can any one suggest me or is it possible to have such kind of order by in my requirement.

Comment: can you also show *expected output*?

Comment: `(select distinct keyTypeId from key where keyTypeId = 2)` will result `2` so basically you want `ORDER BY 2` ??

Comment: Meanig 2nd field in the output of select list.

Comment: i wan to order by KeyTypeName. that was only sample query also updated my post for expected output.

Comment: If the number of results with or without `order by` clause are same, using that clause will affect nothing.

Comment: Can't you just use `order by KeyTypeName` then?

Comment: I can use but it generalizes the keyTypeName. since i was asked to sort by KeyName example key 2 like that. that's why so much confusion.

Comment: @user1268890 can you please add your expected output, bit clearly.

Comment: it is very clear. It displays the rqstId and orchiveId from rqstTable and KeyValue from keyTable

Comment: @user1268890 Then why you need `order by` at all if your output has only one row?

Comment: @user1268890 It might be clear to you, but to someone not familiar with your application, it's totally unclear what your requirements are. Your example is meaningless, since an ORDER BY with a result set that contains only one row is totally superfluous. Please post some *real* input data and the *real* output you expect.

Comment: I have updated my query here. I am trying my best to express my self on the requirement. Mian problem is as part of order by along with column name i have value too like  KeyTypeName='key2'. I believe some times we can have single row as result based on our inputs.

Comment: @user1268890 It is still unclear. Maybe you post the result with more than one row to get your sort order requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select b.KeyValue,
       a.rqstId,
       a.orchiveId,
       case when c.KeyTypeName = 'key2' then 0 else 1 end as KeyTypeNameForOrder
  from rqst a, key b, keyType c
 where a.statusId = 102
   and a.requestType = 4
   and a.processTypeId = 5
   and b.rqstId = a.rqstId     
   and c.KeyTypeId = b.keyTypeId
 order by 4
```

Comment: EDITED to
select b.KeyValue,
       a.rqstId,
       a.orchiveId
  from rqst a, key b, keyType c
 where a.statusId = 102
   and a.requestType = 4
   and a.processTypeId = 5
   and b.rqstId = a.rqstId     
   and c.KeyTypeId = b.keyTypeId
 order by case when c.KeyTypeName = 'key2' then 0 else 1 end;               
I am able to see the Results starting with key2 followed by other keys. Thank you so much. I want to thank everyone for their time and efforts.